# Java: Storing an Array into an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner

Is it possible to store three string values added into an array (studentName), and store that into a different array so it can be found later?

Basically my main goal is to store a name, user id, and a balance (fullName, idName, 300).

And add that into a "super(?)" array so when people type down, it finds the fullName and pulls the information from there.

Comment: Why not create a class (let's say `Person`) and then use an array of `Person`?

Comment: Read about Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: Java is not PHP. You don't abuse arrays to model records/structs in Java. For this, you can abuse class.

Comment: To answer the question as asked: An array is just a kind of object. Yes, you can have an array of arrays. This is probably not the best way to solve the problem you're describing, but it could be done.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. It is called a multidimensional array. No, you should not do this. You should make a class for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I believe you are talking about something like Jagged Array which is available in C# but for java, we can do it in some other ways... like creating a class and manipulating it as Generic List implementation...

```
public class Student {

private String name;
private int id;
private int balanace;

public Student(){}

public Student(String name, int id, int balance){
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.balanace = balance;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public int getBalanace() {
    return balanace;
}
public void setBalanace(int balanace) {
    this.balanace = balanace;
}
```

}

In some other class where you would want to manipulate

```
public class ManipulateData {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Student student1 = new Student("James", 1, 500);
    List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
    list.add(student1);

    for(Student s: list){
        System.out.println("Name : " + s.getName());
        System.out.println("ID : " + s.getId());
        System.out.println("Balance : " + s.getBalanace());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

You can create a class

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String id;
    private int balance;
}
```

and then you can create a list of these objects:

```
List<Student> list = new ArrayList<Student>();
```

---

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

then:

```
List<Map<String, String>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
```

and then:

```
map.put("name", "Thomas");
map.put("id", "Thomas id");
map.put("balance", ""300);
listOfMaps.add(map);
```

Anyhow, be careful. You will have to keep numbers (f.e. balance) as a String and after you will need to map it.

Comment: That sounds more reasonable than my implementation. It was originally just a series of strings. But can these three things be connected together so when someone searches a "fullName", then the ID and balance is tagged with it based on the original entry?

Comment: There's an array that keeps track of other arrays, organized by name. So when a specific array is called, it shows the name, ID, and balance. If it doesn't exist, it adds the array.

So whenever the searcher wants to pull the information, they just do it by name and get all three details. 

I was kinda wordy originally, sorry! @Girly Girl

Comment: **1.** I reckon that you are trying to make things really complicated. **2.** Maybe suitable solution for you could be Map<String, String>. I edited my post - maybe it will suit you.